# cypress run test window goes all white

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, end-to-end

So, I'm writing test in cypress 7 on windows 10 and I don't know why but the cypress window is going all white, I can't do anything except restart my test and the behaviour stay the same. I didn't find anything about this problem on the web.

Also, nothing strange in the logs..

Anyone had this strange behaviour ?

Comment: Are you running a VM or WSL ?

Comment: I'm running wsl on windows 10

Comment: Has it ever worked or is this the first time using cypress ?

Comment: For me it's first time but other team members (2 peoples on windows 10 with wsl too) have the same problem, usualy they close and restart cypress and that's ok for some time but not for me. I tried to switch from cypress 7 to cypress 8.7.0 but same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sometimes happens to me too. But I just close cypress and run it again. If the problem still persists try switching browsers?

Comment: Due to the administrator policies I'm forced to use electron browser, chrome and edge are a no go because cypress is not allowed to control them.
Closing and running again cypress is not always working

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of memory usage. If your memory is low it will cause cypress to crash causing the white screen. Try lowering numTestsKeptInMemory to 5 or 0. If using chromium based chrome, edge or electron then setting up experimentalMemoryManagement to true. Then try running cyress from terminal and close all unnessary application and run it. It won't completely fix it but help avoid it a lot.